# USA basement map or data available

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for information about basement for each state or in USA. They can be either a map, dataset, or on the website.

i am looking for that to get an information about a local in the state of Colorado. My understanding is that each state has its own basement, for example, in California they do not have basement for all or some of the houses due to earthquakes, or like some states in the Midwest some or all ore none  of the houses have their basement because of tornadoes. Some states cannot build basement due to unstable soils under the surface.

I've google it but such as no luck...

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean building code requirements for basements? Typically, these are based on the depth of the frost line. They are typically set on a per country basis, not state.

Here is a graph of the frost lines for continental USA

http://sqfoot.com/pdf/US_Map_Frost_DepthAVG.pdf

Here's a link from Colorado State University where the last FAQ talks about frost lines in the state.

http://climate.colostate.edu/questions.php

Here's a Colorado construction company page talking about frost lines and building foundations.

http://evstudio.com/foundation-construction-%E2%80%93-when-frost-depth-can-not-be-met/

Each county's building code will set minimum depth of the foundation below the frost line.

Comment: This is does not really give me more details about the location...Difficult to understand... sorry

Comment: @PROBERT - can you provide more details on the specific information you are looking for?